# Monitor ECS service communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, monitoring

I need monitor the connections between ECS services in my cluster and by they communication HTTP response codes, especially when using service discovery

How i can do that, i don't want set up agent in my container or change source code of application?